# How to remove Duplicate nodes in xml using xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

---

Hi,

Please help me in removing the duplicate nodes from the xml.Condition to remove duplicate nodes is  quite complicated.

condition 1:In each policy node under policyKey node i have to check policyNbr and PolicyFormCode/code and policyEffectiveDt and policyID
are same in all the policy nodes if they are same i have retain only the policy node which has sourceSystemCd/code='SCBP' present in it.

condition 2:If in the above condition policyNbr and PolicyFormCode/code and policyEffectiveDt and policyID any of this have differnt values i need to display all th policy node.

Input xml: 
  condition 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<policies>
    <!-- policy 1-->
    <policy>
        <policyKey>
            <policyNbr>4567</policyNbr>
            <policyEffectiveDt>2014-11-14</policyEffectiveDt>
            <policyFormCd>
                <code>669</code>
            </policyFormCd>
        </policyKey>
        <transactionSplitTrans>
            <sourceSystemCd>
                <code>ARA</code>
            </sourceSystemCd>
        </transactionSplitTrans>
    </policy> 
    <!-- second -->
    <policy>
        <policyKey>
            <policyNbr>1234</policyNbr>
            <policyID>115774001</policyID>
            <policyEffectiveDt>2014-11-11</policyEffectiveDt>
            <policyFormCd>
                <code>660</code>
            </policyFormCd>
        </policyKey>
        <transactionSplitTrans>
            <sourceSystemCd>
                <code>ARAR</code>
            </sourceSystemCd>
        </transactionSplitTrans>
    </policy>
    <!-- third -->
    <policy>
        <policyKey>
            <policyEffectiveDt>2014-11-14</policyEffectiveDt>
            <policyFormCd>
                <code>660</code>
            </policyFormCd>
            <policyID>115774001</policyID>
            <policyNbr>1234</policyNbr>
        </policyKey>
        <transactionSplitTrans>
            <sourceSystemCd>
                <code>SCBP</code>
            </sourceSystemCd>
        </transactionSplitTrans>
    </policy>
</policies>
```

Expexted Output:

```
    <policies>
    <!-- policy 1-->
<policy>
    <policyKey>
        <policyNbr>4567</policyNbr>
        <policyEffectiveDt>2014-11-14</policyEffectiveDt>
        <policyFormCd>
            <code>669</code>
        </policyFormCd>
    </policyKey>
    <transactionSplitTrans>
        <sourceSystemCd>
            <code>ARA</code>
        </sourceSystemCd>
    </transactionSplitTrans>
</policy>
<!-- third -->
<policy>
    <policyKey>
        <policyEffectiveDt>2014-11-14</policyEffectiveDt>
        <policyFormCd>
            <code>660</code>
        </policyFormCd>
        <policyID>115774001</policyID>
        <policyNbr>1234</policyNbr>
    </policyKey>
    <transactionSplitTrans>
        <sourceSystemCd>
            <code>SCBP</code>
        </sourceSystemCd>
    </transactionSplitTrans>
</policy>
</policies>
```

Condition 2: display all three policyNodes

Comment: So if there are no duplicates, you want to keep one without a policy id?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="/policies/policy">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="./policyKey/policyID">
        <xsl:copy-of select='.'/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name='currNumber' select="number(policyKey/policyNbr)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="currCode" select="policyKey/policyFormCd/code"/>
        <xsl:if test="count(../policy/policyKey[number(policyNbr)=$currNumber and policyFormCd/code=$currCode and policyID]) = 0">
            <xsl:copy-of select='.'/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This should work. If the policy has an ID, then copy it. If not and there isn't a matching one with an id then also copy it. (Could be shorter but this should be clear enough). Tested.

Comment: Added the check for policy code. Numbers are compared with number(policyNbr) to handle the different formats.

Comment: Everywhere in the above code where we have "number(something)", replace with: "substring (concat ('0000000000000000', something), string-length(something)+1, 16)". This pads it out to 16 bytes with leading zeroes and then takes the right-most 16 characters.
If some of the hex values are upper and lower case (eg 7E707 and 7e707) then you will have to wrap that in a transform () statement. Yuck, but that's XSL for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the below part in the above xslt and try...

```
<xsl:variable name='currNumber' select="translate(policyKey/policyNbr,'0*','')"/>


<xsl:if test="count(../policy/policyKey[translate(policyNbr,'0*','')=$currNumber and policyFormCd/code=$currCode and policyID]) = 0">
```

Comment: xslt does not have regular expressions so you cannot specify *leading* zeroes. The above translation would replace all zeroes with nulls.